# export K8S logs in managed cluster

Tags: kubernetes, audit

in unmanaged cluster in order to export the k8s audit log we can use the AuditSink object and redirect the logs to any webhook we would like to . in order to do so we should changed the API server.
in managed cluster the API server is not accessible - is there any way to send the data to webhook as well?
if you can add an example it will be great since i saw the sub/pub option of GCP for example and it seems that i cant use my webhook

Answer (score 0):

Within a managed GKE cluster, the audit logs are sent to Stackdriver Logging. At this time, there is no way to send the logs directly from GKE to a webhook; however, there is a workaround.

You can export the GKE Audit logs from Stackdriver Logging to Pub/Sub using a [log sink](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs#pubsub-overview). You will need to define which GKE Audit logs you will like to export to Pub/Sub.

Once the logs are exported to Pub/Sub, you will then be able to push them from Pub/Sub using your webhook. Cloud Pub/Sub is highly programmable and you can control the data you exchange. Please take a look at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push) for an example about webhooks in Cloud Pub/Sub.